# Scraping from more than one aspx pages with R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am a linguistics student doing experiments in R. I have been looking at other questions and got a lot of help, but I am stuck at the moment as I cannot implement example functions to my case and would love to have some help.

First, I would like to go through every semester from here: http://registration.boun.edu.tr/schedule.htm, and every department here: http://registration.boun.edu.tr/scripts/schdepsel.asp

It is actually a bit easy to generate the list of it as the final link is something like this: http://registration.boun.edu.tr/scripts/sch.asp?donem=2017/2018-3&kisaadi=ATA&bolum=ATATURK+INSTITUTE+FOR+MODERN+TURKISH+HISTORY

Secondly, I need to select the code, name, days and hours of the course and tag the semester, which I did. (probably, I did it extremely poorly, but I did it nevertheless, yay!)

```
library("rvest")
library("dplyr")
library("magrittr")

# define the html
reg <- read_html("http://registration.boun.edu.tr/scripts/sch.asp?donem=2017/2018-3&kisaadi=ATA&bolum=ATATURK+INSTITUTE+FOR+MODERN+TURKISH+HISTORY")

# make the html a list of tables
regtable <- reg %>% html_table(fill = TRUE) 

# tag their year
regtable[[4]][ ,15] <- regtable[[1]][1,2]
regtable[[4]][1,15] <- "Semester"

# Change the Days and Hours to sth usable, but how and to what?
  # parse the dates, T and Th problem?
  # parse the hour 10th hour problem?

# get the necessary info
regtable <- regtable %>% .[4] %>%  as.data.frame() %>% select( . , X1 , X3 , X8 , X9 , V15)

# correct the names
names(regtable) <- regtable[1,]
regtable <- regtable[-1,]
View(regtable)
```

But the problem is that I want to write a function where I can do this for more than 20 semester and more than 50 departments. Any help would be great! I am doing this so that I can work on optimization for class hours for my department.

I guess I can do this better with XML Package, but I could not understand how to use it.

Thanks for any help,
Utku

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answer building upon what you have already done. There are likely more efficient solutions, but this should be a good start. You also don't state how you would like to store the data, so currently what I have made will assign each combination of semester and department to its own data frame, which creates a huge amount for the number of departments. It is not ideal but I don't know how you plan to use the data after collection.

```
library("rvest")
library("dplyr")
library("magrittr")

# Create a Department list
dep_list <- read_html("http://registration.boun.edu.tr/scripts/schdepsel.asp")
# Take the read html and identify all objects of class menu2 and extract the
# href which will give you the final part of the url
dep_list <- dep_list %>% 
    html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@class="menu2"]') %>%
    xml_attr("href")

department_list <- gsub("/scripts/sch.asp?donem=", "", dep_list, fixed = TRUE)

# Create a list for all of the semesters
sem_list <- read_html("http://registration.boun.edu.tr/schedule.htm")
sem_list <- sem_list %>% html_table(fill = TRUE)
# Extract the table from the list needed
semester_df <- sem_list[[2]]
# The website uses a table for the dropdown but the values are all in the second cell
# of the second column as a string
semester_list <- semester_df$X2[2]
# Separate the string into a list at the space characters
semester_list <- unlist(strsplit(semester_list, "\\s+"))

# Loop through the list of departments and within each department loop through the
# list of semesters to get the data you want
for(dep in department_list){
    for(sem in semester_list){
        url <- paste("http://registration.boun.edu.tr/scripts/sch.asp?donem=", sem, dep, sep = "")
        reg <- read_html(url)

        # make the html a list of tables
        regtable <- reg %>% html_table(fill = TRUE) 
        # The data we want is in the 4th portion of the created list so extract that
        regtable <- regtable[[4]]
        # Rename the column headers to the values in the first row and remove the
        # first row
        regtable <- setNames(regtable[-1, ], regtable[1, ])

        # Create semester column and select the variables we want
        regtable <- regtable %>% 
          mutate(Semester = sem) %>% 
          select(Code.Sec, Name, Days, Hours, Semester)

        # Assign the created table to a dataframe
        # Could also save the file here instead
        assign(paste("table", sem, gsub(" ", "_", dep), sep = "_"), regtable)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, Amanda thank you so much for your help! And thank you for your comments. As I stated, I am just experimenting in R with the stuff I find interesting. Being able to get data from the web and such seemed interesting. And the other thing is that our schools schedule planning is shitty. The hours and the days go back and forth with each related departments. So, I thought maybe there are some patterns that each departments have, and being able to work on the data year by year, I can optimize a schedule for my department and tell them the best slots to use if they want less back and forth :)

Comment: Also, after I tried this code I saw that this code only gets from the department named "ATATURK..."  and I guess it is because the "url" in the function has this: "&kisaadi=ATA&bolum=" but also this kisaadi (means shortname in Turkish)variable changes according to the department. How can I add this one too? Maybe like this:

url <- url <- paste("http://registration.boun.edu.tr/scripts/sch.asp?donem=", sem, "&kisaadi=", shortname , "&bolum=", gsub(" ", "+", dep), sep = "")

But I do not know how to get those shortnames, I can do it manually, but I do not want to.

Comment: Oh sorry, I only testing to make sure the looping and everything worked and didn't realize that was part of the url. That would be how you change the url, but to come up with the short names, you would either need to find a page on the university site and pull them in the same manner, or identify if there are any patterns in how the name is determined, i.e. if the string is only one word take the first 4 characters, if the string is multiple words take the first letter of each. If neither of those can be done, I think the only other option would be to pull them manually.

Comment: I actually figured out how to pull the shortname and department name in the same list and have updated the above answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Amanda I was able to achieve what I wanted to do. Only thing left is to scraping shortnames list, match them and do the whole thing, but I can do what I want with creating a list. Any further comments to do this more elegantly are appreciated!

```
library("rvest")
library("dplyr")
library("magrittr")

# Create a Department list
dep_list <- read_html("http://registration.boun.edu.tr/scripts/schdepsel.asp")
dep_list <- dep_list %>% html_table(fill = TRUE)
# Select the table from the html that contains the data we want
department_df <- dep_list[[2]]
# Rename the columns with the value of the first row and remove row
department_df <- setNames(department_df[-1, ], department_df[1, ])
# Combine the two columns into a list
department_list <- c(department_df[, 1], department_df[, 2])
# Edit the department list
# We can choose accordingly.
department_list <- department_list[c(7,8,16,20,26,33,36,37,38,39)]


# Create a list for all of the semesters
sem_list <- read_html("http://registration.boun.edu.tr/schedule.htm")
sem_list <- sem_list %>% html_table(fill = TRUE)
# Extract the table from the list needed
semester_df <- sem_list[[2]]
# The website uses a table for the dropdown but the values are all in the second cell
# of the second column as a string
semester_list <- semester_df$X2[2]
# Separate the string into a list at the space characters
semester_list <- unlist(strsplit(semester_list, "\\s+"))
# Shortnames string
# We can add whichever we want.
shortname_list <- c("FLED", "HIST" , "PSY", "LL" , "PA" , "PHIL" , "YADYOK" , "SOC" , "TR" , "TKL" )
# Length
L = length(department_list)

# the function to get the schedule for the selected departments 
for( i in 1:L){
  for(sem in semester_list){tryCatch({
    dep <- department_list[i]
    sn <- shortname_list[i]
    url_second_part <- interaction("&kisaadi=" , sn, "&bolum=", gsub(" ", "+", (gsub("&" , "%26", dep))), sep = "", lex.order = TRUE)
    url <- paste("http://registration.boun.edu.tr/scripts/sch.asp?donem=", sem, url_second_part, sep = "")
    reg <- read_html(url)

    # make the html a list of tables
    regtable <- reg %>% html_table(fill = TRUE) 
    # The data we want is in the 4th portion of the created list so extract that
    regtable <- regtable[[4]]
    # Rename the column headers to the values in the first row and remove the
    # first row
    regtable <- setNames(regtable[-1, ], regtable[1, ])

    # Create semester column and select the variables we want
    regtable <- regtable %>% 
      mutate(Semester = sem) %>% 
      select(Code.Sec, Name, Days, Hours, Semester)

    # Assign the created table to a dataframe
    # Could also save the file here instead
    assign(paste("table", sem, gsub(" ", "_", dep), sep = "_"), regtable)
  }, error = function(e){cat("ERROR : No information on this" , url , "\n" )})
  }
}  

### Maybe make Errors another dataset or list too.
```